# What part of speech is 'better' in the following sentence?

Tags: nouns, adverbs, parts-of-speech, comparatives

What part of speech is *better* in the following sentence? Is it an [adverb](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/adverbs.htm) because it modifies the verb *expect*? Is it an [abstract noun](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/abstract_nouns.htm) because it is an “intangible concept such as an emotion, a feeling, a quality, or an idea”. Or is it a [comparative adjective](https://www.thoughtco.com/comparative-degree-adjectives-and-adverbs-1689881)?

> *We expect **better** from our royal family on whom we spend millions and millions of pounds for training and schooling.*

I'm teaching English in Japan and I am a Japanese. When we read the following material in an article (2009) by *The Guardian*: [Politicians condemn Prince Harry over 'racist' remark](https://www.theguardian.com/uk/2009/jan/12/prince-harry-video-pakistani)

One of my students asked me about the above sentence. He asked me what part of speech is *better* in that sentence: Noun? Adjective? Or adverb? – I'm also wondering.

And also, I would like to ask the following, is it possible to reposition *better* in the following?

> We expect our royal family **better**, on whom we spend millions and millions of pounds for training and schooling?

or

> We expect **better** things from our royal family on whom we spend millions and millions of pounds for training and schooling.?

Comment: Not better *thing*, but possibly better *behaviour* or *responses* etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
Do you have any idea what part of speech is 'better' in "We expect better from our royal family on whom we spend millions and millions of pounds for training and schooling."?

Comment: I just found something from a dictionary. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. The first two dictionaries I checked in gave the expected answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth What's the expected answer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Thanks for your advice. I've edited the question.

Comment: @ Mari-Lou A  I really thank you for your voting and editing.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't have intervened if you hadn't first improved your question in your edit.  The question was on topic but some users, reasonably, wanted to see some evidence of research. So, next time, share your research :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thanks again for your editing and for your advice. I'll try to do my best next time!
I also thanks for other users' editing and warnings.

Comment: @JapaneseEnglishteacher: Don't forget, the Japanese don't have comparative forms in a single word. In Japanese you need to use at least a phrase to suggest the comparison: どちらのほうが良いですか？(Lit., "Which of these is good?" meaning "Which of these is better?") So the concept of a standalone word that encompasses these circumlocutions, which may be responsible for some of the confusion in your students.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like an adjective with an elided noun (e.g. better *behaviour*, better *responses*), but in the given context ODO treats it as a noun.

> **better** *noun*
>   1 (mass noun) The better one; that which is better.
>   ‘you've a right to expect better than that’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/better)

---

*The following is a sketch why I'm equivocating.*

The intention appears to be that the author was disappointed with some aspect of the royal family's behaviour, expecting it (the behaviour) to be better.

Had the expression been "expect better behaviour", there would be no question that *better* serves as an adjective, modifying *behaviour*:

> **better** *adjective*
>   1 More desirable, satisfactory, or effective.
>   ‘we're hoping for better weather tomorrow’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/better)

Eliding "behaviour" from the phrase reduces the noun phrase "better behaviour" to the single word "better". The sense still carries, though, which is perhaps why it is categorised as a noun in that context. Linguists have expressed that ellipsis is held as something of a last resort, so I'll just leave this as a plausibility argument, rather than a definitive one. Nevertheless, this seems to be a layman's description of BillJ's more articulate comment:

> I'd call it a 'fused modifier-head' construction, where the adjective "better" serves as modifier and as head at the same time. In other words "better" is an NP headed by the adjective "better". – [BillJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451882/what-part-of-speech-is-better-in-the-following-sentence/451884?noredirect=1#comment1088058_451884)

In comments to this answer, it was suggested that "better" could be an adverb, comparing the royal family to other families. I find this a little hard to justify syntactically from your original quote. The quote doesn't even hint at a comparison with other families; it's a statement that talks exclusively about one family. Now, it's possible to argue that *better* modifies *expect*, but that changes the natural sense of the quote.

---

Regarding the rephrasings: splicing the noun phrase into "expect better" doesn't produce an idiomatic expression, and "better *things*" doesn't quite capture the original sense related to *behaviour*; it might work if the original related to *circumstances* or *situations*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Why the equivocation?

Comment: I'd call it a 'fused modifier-head' construction, where the adjective "better" serves as modifier and as head at the same time. In other words "better" is an NP headed by the adjective "better".

Comment: Thank you for all comments. 
My English friend who is teaching English in Japan says that  he  thinks ‘better’ is the comparative adverb e.g. We expect better from our royal family (than other families)
But  he gives me second thoughts--- ‘better’ is technically a comparative abstract noun replacing ‘better behaviour’, where better is a comparative adjective. He points out that  the confusion over whether it’s a comparative adverb arises because of the verb ‘expect’.

Comment: Another English friend (who is also teaching English in Japan) says that 'expect better' is a kind of typical common phrase, a bit formal phrase, so they do not divide into 'part of speech'. I'm just wondering how I explain it to my students.

Comment: @Kris I've edited to sketch the reason for the equivocation.

Comment: @BillJ That sounds like just the thing!

Comment: @JapaneseEnglishteacher Thanks for sharing your friends' comments. I've edited to take them into account.

Comment: A bit leggy. Recommended action is remove everything after the sentence containing "last resort" inclusivenely.